# how to get older window 7 OS to install dual signed files

Tags: code-signing

Our dual signed software is not installing on older windows 7 OS versions.

The install error is:
Windows cannot verify the digital signature for the drivers required for this device. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source. (Code 52)

Our code signing certificate was recently updated to SHA256.

My research found that I had to dual-sign binaries so the signatures will validate on older versions of Windows that don't support SHA-256.

Thanks to the contributors to this site, I was able to modify all the components of our existing build scripts to successfully dual-sign binaries.

They do install in several Windows 10 OS versions and Windows 7 with the security update for SHA-256 certificates.
They do not install in windows 7 OS without the update.

Our build machine is 32 bit Win 7, so I am using the x86 version of signtool.exe from the 8.1 Windows kit that ships with VS 2015, its version is 6.3.9600.17298

I have found conflicting info about windows 7 and it's ability to install dual signed CAT files.

SO I am searching for a method to get code installed on all version of windows 7 and 10, regardless of the state of their windows updates. (some customers do not regularly update the OS and prefer to keep it that way)

UPDATE: I was able to get our appl and drivers to install to older windows 7 OS versions. Turns out the code signing certificate was not setup correctly to allow for dual signing.

I had to get the certificate re-issued as a SHA256 with SHA1 root for code signing.

Comment: Is your update an answer? If so, you can provide it below instead of an edit to your question

Answer (score 0):

After success with last weeks test setup, we made an official build of our entire software suite (that includes USB device drivers).
We tested software install and operation on the following machines:

32 bit Windows 7 Ultimate Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601

64 bit Windows 7 Professional Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
  Original ISO version, no OS updates

64 bit Windows 7 Professional Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
  OS updates including KB3033929 for SHA256 compatibility

64 bit Windows 7 Home Basic Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601

64 bit Windows 10 Pro Version 10.0.10586 Build 10586

64 bit Windows 10 Home Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.10)

64 bit Windows 10 Pro  Insider Preview Version 1607 (OS Build 14971.1000)

All of those tests produced a successful app and driver installation.

So, the answer was to change the type of code signing certificate installed on the build machine.

The certificate had to be installed as a SHA256 with SHA1 root. CertMgr displays 2 separate certificates, one with hash=SHA1, second with hash=SHA256.

Then the build scripts were modified to create a dual signature. First call to signtool creates the SHA1 sign, second call to signtool appends the SHA2 sign.
(NOTE: Only Windows SDK 8.1 and higher supports dual signing.)